# Unable to convert Images stored in resource file to Base64 string in Asp.net [C#]

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get images stored in resource file and then trying to convert it to base64 string. however it generate garbage string below is my code:

```
String imgBase64=Base64FromByteArray(ExtractResource(Properties.Resources.products_tipp_110));

public static byte[] ExtractResource(Bitmap image)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
        if (ms == null)
            return null;
        byte[] imageByteArray = new byte[ms.Length];
        ms.Read(imageByteArray, 0, imageByteArray.Length);
        return imageByteArray;
    }

private static string Base64FromByteArray(byte[] image)
    {
        return "base64:" + Convert.ToBase64String(image);
    }


output: 
   base64:AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA..... with all A's
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this `byte[] imageByteArray = ms.ToArray()` to convert the memory stream into byte array as below.

Also, make sure your image is `png` as you have used `ImageFormat.Png`

```
String imgBase64=Base64FromByteArray(ExtractResource(Properties.Resources.products_tipp_110));

public static byte[] ExtractResource(Bitmap image)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
        if (ms == null)
            return null;
        byte[] imageByteArray = ms.ToArray();;
        return imageByteArray;
    }

private static string Base64FromByteArray(byte[] image)
    {
        return "base64:" + Convert.ToBase64String(image);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this function Image and the format of Image, it will return you string.

```
 public string ImageToBase64(Image image, 
      System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
    {
      using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
        // Convert Image to byte[]
        image.Save(ms, format);
        byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

        // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        return base64String;
      }
    }
```